# `\pounds` misbehaving with the `eulervm` package even in T1 encoding

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, eulervm

I am teaching a probability course involving lots of gambling and hence, since I'm in the UK, I would like to use £ in some formulae.  I use `utf8x` input enconding, `T1` font encoding and the `eulervm` maths fonts.  Nevertheless, £ inside math-mode comes out like a dollar sign.

Here's a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[small]{eulervm}

\begin{document}

A gambler wins $£1$ with probability $p$ and loses $£1$ with probability $1-p$.

\end{document}
```

Commenting out the line which calls the `eulervm` package works, but I really like the `eulervm` fonts, so any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: In the meantime I'm putting the £ outside math-mode, so it's not as if this is critical, but I would like to know the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using `utf8` instead of `utf8x` and of leaving `£` outside of math mode, to which it doesn't belong.

If you want to use it in math mode you have to teach how to LaTeX

### Method A (`utf8` option):

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A3}{\text{\textsterling}}
```

### Method B (`utf8x` option):

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\uc@dclc{163}{default}{\text{\textsterling}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am undecided about leaving the £ outside of math mode.  I tend to agree that they detract from the maths, yet at the same the currency is a system of units and just as in physics formulae,  the units are often part of the equation.

Comment: One question: why do you recommend `utf8` instead of `utf8x`?  I must admit I forgot why I made that choice when I thought about that problem.

Comment: `utf8x` is not maintained and it's incompatible with some packages, notably `biblatex`.